# FIDO and FIDO2 differences

Tags: u2f, fido, webauthn, fido2

I've been reading both FIDO and FIDO2 specs for a while tring to understand the similarities and differences between both. Here is how I broke it down so far:

- FIDO: First iteration in creating a cross industry  standard for passwordless / 2fa experience (with UAF and U2F)
- FIDO2: Second iteration (with CTAP and Webauthn)
- U2F: specifies a Javascript API and a HID protocol for FIDO
- CTAP: specifies a HID protocol for FIDO2
- Webauthn: specifies a Javascript API for FIDO2

Do you think this is accurate? Any other information you think is useful?

Comment: This article seems to have a pretty good summary of the various standards: https://blog.strongkey.com/blog/guide-to-fido-protocols-u2f-uaf-webauthn-fido2

Comment: @natevw additionally the article explains the difference between FIDO UAF and FIDO(1),FIDO2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right except for few points to let me break it down for you.

- FIDO: First iteration in creating a cross-industry standard for passwordless / 2fa experience (with UAF and U2F) ---> Yes you are right about but remember FIDO 1.0 never achieved standardization

---

- FIDO2: Second iteration (with CTAP and Webauthn) --> Partially right about FIDO2.0. It comprised of WebAuthn (the Browser API) W3C standard and CTAP2 (the authenticator API) (formally known as U2F/CTAP1) and also FIDO Alliance relabeled U2F as CTAP1. Quite confusing but yeah we have to live with it.

---

- U2F: specifies a Javascript API and a HID protocol for FIDO --> Yes you are right

---

- CTAP: specifies a HID protocol for FIDO2 --> Yes you are right. CTAP is like client-side protocol to establish communication with external security keys.

---

- Webauthn: specifies a Javascript API for FIDO2 --> Perfect

Comment: "CTAP2 (the authenticator API) (formally known as U2F/CTAP1) and also FIDO Alliance relabeled U2F as CTAP1" - are you saying that CTAP2 is known as U2F/CTAP1, and U2F is relabeled as CTAP1, so U2F/CTAP1 is essentially CTAP1 so CTAP2 is known as CTAP1?